# Return only 5 unique random objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Have a page that shows 1 restaurant and below is the list of 5 suggested restaurants = objects (random list of restaurants with various properties such as the name of the restaurant, cusineType, rating, location). Returning back 5 random objects.

```
var random = new Random(); var results = restaurants.Where(restaurant => restaurant.cusineType == "Sushi").OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(5).ToList();
```

With the current setup, it returns 5 random restaurants, but:

- it can return in the list the same restaurant as the one loaded on the page
- it can return 2 same objects in the list

How to make it return only unique 5 random objects?

Answer (score 0):

you can use skip() and take() on the list and get a random entities.

```
var distributes = _home.GetDistributeCenter().ToList();
Random rand = new Random();
int toSkip = rand.Next(0, distributes.Count - 6);
var randomlist = distributes.Skip(toSkip).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @fatima_h66. Can you explain what is _home.GetDistributeCenter() ?

Comment: hi, this is a return list of objects, you can put every list instead of it.

Comment: Hmm..it doesn't work well, unfortunately.